What is the difference when we call withContext with coroutineContext and Job?
I am confused about working with withContext in Coroutine. I was calling withContext in a suspend function with the IO dispatcher. In that case, in some situations, the coroutine is canceled because the viewmodel is destroyed. So I came up with the idea of changing coroutineContext using withContext. But I found different approaches. Now I am confused about which method is best. I am sharing those methods below. Help me find the best approach from the below samples and also let me any of them have anti pattern.
class MyRepositoryOne {

   private val scope= CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob())
   suspend fun reset()= withContext(scope.coroutineContext){}
}

class MyRepositoryTwo {

   private val job= SupervisorJob()
   suspend fun reset()= withContext(job){}
}

class MyRepositoryThree {

   suspend fun reset()= withContext(SupervisorJob()){}
}

class MyRepositoryFour {

   suspend fun reset()= withContext(CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob()).coroutineContext){}
}


If I understand correctly you want a coroutine that outlives the view model. None of your approaches will do that, though.
The key is that a coroutine only lives as long as its scope where the coroutine was launched in. Since your repositories expose suspend functions these functions can only be called when a coroutine is already running. That will be the one created by viewModelScope.launch { ... }. It doesn't matter what you do with withContext, the coroutine will be cancelled when the viewModelScope is cancelled (which happens when the view model is destroyed).
If you want your coroutine to outlive the view model you need to use another scope. In Android that should be a scope that lives in your application class. There are several ways you can get one. If you use Hilt for dependency injection you could do this: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/create-an-application-coroutinescope-using-hilt-dd444e721528, otherwise see this question: Coroutine scope on Application class android.
Then you can remove the suspend modifier from the repository function and launch a new coroutine in the repository with this new application scope.
You shouldn't create new coroutine scopes inside your repository though, that makes it opaque what coroutines are running. Either provide a scope to the repository so it can launch new coroutines (here the application scope) or expose suspend functions in the repository so that the caller can decide which coroutine to use.
If you want your coroutine to outlive your entire app you should use a WorkManager instead.

When the ViewModel is cleared, the viewModelScope cancels all its children (meaning all coroutines started by it either using launch{} or async{})
Since withContext(CoroutineContext) inherits its coroutineContext from the parent's scope (often the viewModelScope) to support structured concurrency, when the parent is cancelled, withContext(CoroutineContext) is cancelled as well.
The difference with other coroutine scope functions( coroutineScope{}, supervisorScope{} and withTimeOut(timeInMillis){}) is that withContext allows some changes to be made to the scope.
The context provided as an argument to withContext(CoroutineContext) function overrides the context from the parent scope and thus withContext is often used to set a different coroutine scope for part of our code(Usually to switch between Dispatchers).
Note that passing the Job(either Job() or SupervisorJob()) as argument the way you're doing in Second and Third repositories is considered as bad practice because it destroys the parent-child relationship (Structured Concurrency) between the outer scope and withContext and in this case the Job you're passing becomes the parent of withContext, and withContext will no longer get cancelled when the viewModel is destroyed (in fact it will never get cancelled because the Job will remain in the active state if you don't cancel or complete it manually)
If you want the process in the withContext(CoroutineContext){} body to live longer than the current ViewModel, the best practice would be to inject a CoroutineScope (define by a component that lives longer than your current ViewModel typically the Application or the MainActivity ViewModel if you're using a single activity) in the repository, ensuring proper structured concurrency and resource management, thus withContext will be cancelled along with the scope it inherits from.
